# Best way of global registering ClientScript?

Tags: yii

I want to register user script globally, to be available all over the site. Now I insert in every action in my controllers:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/js/script.js');
```

But really I understand that it's not good way...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are looking forward to use themes in your project, i would put some css and scripts in layout file (**views/layouts/my-layout-file.php**). Because if you changing theme you will be using another css and maybe sometimes another scripts, so you would not want to mix it together.

But some main css and scipts, that didn't change accross themes, i would put in main **Controller** (protected/components/Controller.php)
And all other controllers (/protected/controllers/) would extend this class Controller

```
class PageController extends Controller {
```

And so if all your controllers using on parent class, you can edit just parent class and add something like this

```
public function beforeRender( $view ) {
    ...
    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/js/script.js');
    ...
    return true;
}
```

And all your actions will be now using same script.

**EDIT**: @realtebo (in comments) pointed out to use '[beforeRender](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#beforeRender-detail)' not 'beforeAction'.

See more: [Understanding the view rendering flow](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/249/understanding-the-view-rendering-flow/)

Comment: oh, it's sounds and looks more accurate! Thanks @realtebo

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in this way : initiate init function  in base controller class having path protected/components/controller.php

```
public function init()
{
  Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/js/script.js'); 
  parent::init();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to register global js and css files I think is registering them in beforeRender() method (not in beforeAction() - because if you render json or xml this may destroy your structure) of some BaseController.

Answer (score 0):

U can do like this:
1. create private attribute $_assetsUrl;
2. then in the module or controller

```
public function getAssetsUrl()
{
    if ($this->_assetsUrl===null)
    {
        $assetsPath = $this->basePath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'assets';
        $this->_assetsUrl = Yii::app()->assetManager->publish($assetsPath,false,-1,YII_DEBUG);
        if (Yii::app()->theme!==null && is_dir($assetsPath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.Yii::app()->theme->name))
            $this->_assetsUrl .= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.Yii::app()->theme->name;
    }
    return $this->_assetsUrl;
}
```

Hope this was useful, see also this link http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/148/understanding-assets/