# How do I include jquery plugin in Yii framework?

Tags: php, jquery, css, yii, assets

I have a problem when I include jquery's plugin, image isn't visible. The image is included in a css file.

```
div{background-image:url('famfamfam.png');background-repeat:no-
repeat;width:16px;height:16px}
```

[That plugin](http://www.sceditor.com/documentation/getting-started/)

example of my attempts. The code placed at

> /webroot/protected/components/MyWidjet.php

in a method

> init()

```
$cs = Yii::app()->clientScript;
        $cs->registerCssFile(Yii::app()->assetManager->publish(dirname(__FILE__).'/css/ 
 editor.css'));
     $cs->registerPackage(Yii::app()->assetManager->publish(dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/
 minified/'));
        $cs->registerCssFile(Yii::app()->assetManager->publish(dirname(__DIR__) .
                '/vendor/minified/themes/default.min.css'));
        $cs->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->assetManager->publish(dirname(__DIR__) .
                '/vendor/minified/jquery.sceditor.bbcode.min.js'));

  echo CHtml::script("$(function() {
            $('textarea').sceditor({
                plugins: 'bbcode',
                toolbar: 
  'bold,italic,horizontalrule,underline,strike,subscript,superscript|left,center,right,\
                justify|size,color|bulletlist,orderedlist|table|
  code,quote,image,link,unlink|maximize,source',
            locale: 'ru',
            charset: 'utf-8',
            autofocus: true,
            enablePasteFiltering: true,
            spellcheck: true,
            style: 'minified/jquery.sceditor.default.min.css'
            });
        });");
```

Access rights are 777

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it theme-wide:

Add the clientScript calls to your themes/themename/views/layouts/main.php in the head, or wherever you want.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery'); ?>    
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('cookie'); ?>        
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
.....
```

Or you can add them to controller methods, or in various other places.  But this will make sure Jquery is plagged in everywhere :)

Answer (score 0):

http://codingtip.blogspot.com/2013/09/yii-register-client-script-add-javascript-css-file.html

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/5309-clientscript-register/

http://code.dimilow.com/yii-adding-javascript-into-your-views/

http://www.waytoblogger.com/2012/08/13/register-js-css-files-in-yii-framework/

[Best way of global registering ClientScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025189/best-way-of-global-registering-clientscript)

:D

UPDATE: for every document you have to give relative path from index.php, since all requests are handled there

Comment: it isn't the answer on my question. That description how include a script and a css but I have another problem. When I include the css file the jquery's plagin is included but image in the file don't include.

Comment: Is it true to put the editor in a layout or a controller folder how there is said?

Comment: [jquery's plagin](http://www.sceditor.com/documentation/getting-started/)
I'm doing the editor for adding news